# Using Raspberry Pi to produce 'beep' through piezo transducer

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio, beep, transducer

I'd like to use my Raspberry Pi to produce a brief, high-pitched (and preferably loud) 'beep' through a piezo transducer.

I tried connecting the + of the transducer to a GPIO pin (and the -ve to GND), and making the pin go high briefly. This worked, but it's more of a very quiet click rather than a loud beep.

Does anyone know how to produce a beep?

Thanks!

Comment: There are different buzzers. One kind is which needs a DC level only to beep on a fixed frequency, and the other (more common) is which requires an AC signal to render it to sound. I think you have the 2nd type. Try alternating the GPIO pin between high and low, with 1ms in between. You'll get a deafening 1kHz beep. Or get another buzzer, that only needs DC to make it work. However, I'd be a bit worried about the GPIO pin - at least to check the manual if it can withstand the nonütrivial load the piezo transducer puts on it. Would be a better question for http://electronics.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the raspberry pi os connected straight to the piezo, no amplifier?

1. Make sure the gpio can output the power required by the transducer.
2. Try toggling the gpio at a frequency in our hearing range, somewhere between 20Hz to 20KHz.